# Guice creation Exception - No bound Assited

Tags: java, guice

```
class ClassA {
    protected ClassA(Injector baseGraph, 
                     BlobStoreContext context,
                     SwiftApi api,
                     @Memoized Supplier<Set<? extends Location>> locations,
                     @Assisted String regionId,PayloadSlicer slicer,
                     @Named(PROPERTY_USER_THREADS) ListeningExecutorService userExecutor) {
     }
}

class ClassB extends ClassA {
    protected ClassB(Injector baseGraph,
                     BlobStoreContext context,
                     SwiftApi api,
                     @Memoized Supplier<Set<? extends Location>> locations,
                     @Assisted String regionId,
                     PayloadSlicer slicer,
                     @Named(PROPERTY_USER_THREADS) ListeningExecutorService userExecutor) {
        super(baseGraph, context, api, locations, regionId, slicer, userExecutor);
    }

}

class C extends AbstractModule {

    protected void configure() {
        bind(classA).to(classB);
    }
}
```

There some problem in the constructor args while binding.

Error that am getting

> Caused by: com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:
>
> 1) No implementation for java.lang.String annotated with @com.google.inject.assistedinject.Assisted(value=) was bound.
>     while locating java.lang.String annotated with @com.google.inject.assistedinject.Assisted(value=)
>       for parameter 4 at

Comment: Why do you call constructor of the superclass of `ClassB` in `ClassB`'s constructor? This is normally not advised.

Answer (score 0):

`@Assisted` is used in the context of [assisted injection](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AssistedInject), which is a Guice feature that automatically implements a factory for you that mixes normal constructor parameters with Guice-provided parameter injections. For instance, here:

```
class ClassB extends ClassA {
    protected ClassB(Injector baseGraph,
                     BlobStoreContext context,
                     SwiftApi api,
                     @Memoized Supplier<Set<? extends Location>> locations,
                     @Assisted String regionId,
                     PayloadSlicer slicer,
                     @Named(PROPERTY_USER_THREADS) ListeningExecutorService userExecutor) {
        super(baseGraph, context, api, locations, regionId, slicer, userExecutor);
    }

}
```

I would expect to see this interface:

```
public interface ClassBFactory {
  ClassB create(String regionId);
}
```

Which you would then bind in your AbstractModule subclass like this:

```
install(new FactoryModuleBuilder().build(ClassBFactory.class));
```

Guice can then inspect the ClassBFactory interface, observe the `ClassB` return value, match the `String regionId` parameter of `create` to the `@Assisted String regionId` parameter of your constructor, and then provide this `ClassBFactory` instance to your graph. At that point, rather than injecting `ClassB`, you inject a `ClassBFactory` and then call `classBFactory.create("foo")` to create a `ClassB` with its `regionId` set to `"foo"`.

However, if you try to inject `ClassB` rather than `ClassBFactory`, Guice will not give your `@Assisted` annotation any special treatment, and will not be able to inject that field. Search your codebase to see if a factory interface exists, and if not, you'll need to create one (or otherwise redesign your constructor).